# Can someone explain to me what this **diff** means..?

Tags: files, terminal, command, diff

I'm having an extremely hard time to read this can someone explain what it means, and what the difference between the two is ?

```
$> diff -U 3 user_output_test1 test1.output | cat -e
--- user_output_test1   2018-10-31 22:21:45.000000000 -0700$
+++ test1.output        2018-10-31 22:21:45.000000000 -0700$
@@ -9,8 +9,8 @@$
 '-+2A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0$
 '+-2A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0$
 '++2A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0$
-'2-A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0$
-'+2-A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0$
+'2-A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=2$
+'+2-A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=2$
 '2a' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0$
 '' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0$
 '22' '2'=0$
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_output_test1` has two lines:

```
'2-A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0
'+2-A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=0
```

that differ from `test1.output`, who has these two lines, instead:

```
'2-A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=2
'+2-A' '0123456789ABCDEF'=2
```

The substantive difference being the `=0` turning into `=2`'s.

The leading `-` symbol indicates lines that would be removed from the first file, while the leading `+` symbol indicates lines that would need to be *added to* the first file in order to result in the second file.

The unified diff `-U` is what creates this general `diff` format, while the `3` reinforces the default context of 3 lines around each change. Those "context" lines have a leading space instead of a `+` or `-`.

Adding `cat -e` simply added the trailing `$` symbols.